# include php has different charset

Tags: php

I need a little help. I am totally stuck on this one.

My basic setting is running UTF-8.

But I have included a php file which is scraping data from another site, this site is encoded in ISO-8859-1.

```
<?php

//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.hyde.dk/hanstholm/vejrstation.asp');

echo $html->find('.vsdatatable', 4)->plaintext . "<br>";
echo $html->find('.vsdatatable', 1)->plaintext . "<br>";
echo $html->find('.vsdatatable', 2)->plaintext . "<br>";
echo $html->find('.vsdatatable', 5)->plaintext . "<br>";
echo $html->find('.vsdatatable', 6)->plaintext . "<br>";
echo $html->find('.vsdatatable', 9)->plaintext . "<br>";
echo $html->find('.vsdatatable', 7)->plaintext . "<br>";
echo $html->find('.vsdatatable', 3)->plaintext . "<br>";
echo $html->find('.vsdatatable', 11)->plaintext . "<br>";
echo $html->find('.vsdatatable', 10)->plaintext . "<br>";

$html->save();

$html->clear(); 
unset($html);

?>
```

If i use this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

It overwrites my whole site, and everything else is shown wrong.

Can somebody help me guiding me in the right direction for setting this up in the right way.

Kind regards 
Lasse

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php before building your HTML structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try encoding everything to UTF8.

```
<?php

//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.hyde.dk/hanstholm/vejrstation.asp');

echo utf8_encode($html->find('.vsdatatable', 4)->plaintext) . "<br>";
echo utf8_encode($html->find('.vsdatatable', 1)->plaintext) . "<br>";
echo utf8_encode($html->find('.vsdatatable', 2)->plaintext) . "<br>";
echo utf8_encode($html->find('.vsdatatable', 5)->plaintext) . "<br>";
echo utf8_encode($html->find('.vsdatatable', 6)->plaintext) . "<br>";
echo utf8_encode($html->find('.vsdatatable', 9)->plaintext) . "<br>";
echo utf8_encode($html->find('.vsdatatable', 7)->plaintext) . "<br>";
echo utf8_encode($html->find('.vsdatatable', 3)->plaintext) . "<br>";
echo utf8_encode($html->find('.vsdatatable', 11)->plaintext) . "<br>";
echo utf8_encode($html->find('.vsdatatable', 10)->plaintext) . "<br>";

$html->save();

$html->clear(); 
unset($html);

?>
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: Thanks, that helped me alot. Suddenly I understand it a little too.